# When scaffolding in Geddy, what is the difference between a data-type "default" and not putting a data type?

Tags: geddy

For example:

```
geddy gen scaffold person name:default
```

and

```
geddy gen scaffold person name
```

both create a property "name" with data-type "string." Is there any difference between these two syntaxes?

Answer (score 0):

from [Geddy](http://geddyjs.org/tutorial) documentation:

`$ geddy gen scaffold user name:default`
`This example creates scaffolding but includes name as the default property that will be used when displaying the content in the views.`

`In this example the property name is given the type string because no type was given. You could have also written name:string:default (or some other type in place of 'string'). If no default property is given Geddy will use id as the default display property.`

When you provide a property without type [Geddy](http://geddyjs.org/tutorial) will asume its type is `string`.

`default` by the other hand tells [Geddy](http://geddyjs.org/tutorial) to use that property instead of the `id` attribute as default display property.

for example: if you do a `$ geddy gen scaffold user name:default` [Geddy](http://geddyjs.org/tutorial) will generate the property `name` as string and in the `index.html` after you create a `user` the property that will be shown in the list will be the `name` instead of the `id`.